# Cannot use or update WMware Fusion in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, vmware

I was using VMWare Fusion 3.0 in Snow Leopard before upgrading to Mountain Lion. Now I cannot open or upgrade VMWare Fusion, the icon is blocked, and if clicked, a pop up comes out and if click help, another popup telling me that nothing is available.

How to upgrade and use VMWare fusion again?

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 4):

The [latest version of VMWare Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/overview.html) is version 4. If you want to use VMWare on Mountain Lion, unfortunately you can no longer use the old version. [This VMWare blog post](http://blogs.vmware.com/teamfusion/2012/07/vmware-fusion-and-os-x-mountain-lion-faq.html) says:

> #### Does VMware Fusion 3 work with Mountain Lion?
>
> No. VMware Fusion 3 was released in October 2009 and was optimized for Mac OS X Leopard and Snow Leopard.  VMware Fusion 3 is no longer being updated for newer versions of Mac OS. Customers wishing to run VMware Fusion on Mountain Lion should use VMware Fusion 4. A free 30-day trial is available for current VMware Fusion 3 users. The trial can be found here: http://www.vmware.com/go/tryfusion